# how does this given condition translate into this specific interval (calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

in my calculus book i am learning how derivatives affect the shape of the graph, for one problem i am supposed to sketch a graph given the conditions. I understand when f'(x)>0 the f(x) will increase and when f'(x)<0 it will decrease.

How do i know this given condition: **f'(x)>0 if |x|<2** translates to the interval (-2,2).

as well as **f'(x)<0 if |x|>2** translates to the interval (-inf,-2) U (2,inf).

Comment: Are you asking why $|x|<2$ is equivalent to $-2<x<2$, and $|x|>2$ is equivalent to $x<-2$ or $x>2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first condition implies that $f(x)$ is increasing for $-2<x<2$. Just sketch a graph, perhaps a straight line, that does so.

Your second condition implies that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x<-2$ and also for $2<x$. Just sketch a graph, perhaps a pair of straight lines, that does so.

Many functions can satisify both conditions at once. One example (using curves, not straight lines) is

$$f(x)=12x-x^3$$

[image: Graph of f(x)=12x-x^3]